# Hoodies in the gym

Tags: workout, gym, clothing

I am noticing that so many guys are wearing hoodies while working out in the gym.

the weather outside is really nice (it is spring now in Melbourne Australia)
add to that working out.

I am sweating during my workout and i wear T-shirt and shorts, while some other guys wearing hoodies.

I rolled out that could be due they are not happy with their body as they are really muscular guys with really nice body shape.

So what is the reason for that?!

Comment: It could be a variety of different reasons for different people, so this question is primarily opinion-based. However, I think @twyxz has pretty much nailed it the answer. Personally, I some times wear a hoodie *because* I want to sweat as much as possible, and stay warm even during extended pauses between sets.

Answer (score 0):

> they are not happy with their body

This could be the case, However:

- For me its more comfortable to lift in a hoodie (gets me in the mind set)
- Some people don't sweat as much maybe their workout doesn't have much volume so they decide to wear hoodies to ensure they still sweat.

Theres a range of reasons, usually just personal preferences for example some people just may care about appearance and don't want to show anything whether they're happy with their bodies or not or even they see themselves as better looking with hoodies on... this is largely down to personal preference.